# Adding a driver to an Android tablet

Tags: android, c, linux, driver, embedded-linux

I'm creating a camera driver for Android. I've got my mydriver.c file.
Apparently I need to compile it into a .ko, is that right ?

And then to load it I should do a
`#insmod ./mymodule.ko`, will it work ?

Do I need to be root ? And how I put the .ko file on my Android tablet ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to be root. And, insmod ./yourmodule.ko should work fine.

Comment: So, I need to root my device ? And how I transfer my .ko file ?

Comment: Yes, must be root. You can keep it on any available storage you have. Note, you've to compile your module with appropriate Android toolchain.

Comment: What do you mean ? Can you explain plz?

Comment: :) you might've to use Android NDK to compile your module.

Comment: Just need to install it for libraries or things like that ? Nothing else to do ?

Comment: Well to learn how can you cross compile a module, use google to find out, "cross compile kernel module". Hope this will clarify

Comment: Just one more question: Does Android NDK install the prebuilt for arm-eabi ? If it doesn't, do you know where can I get it for iMX 6 tablet ?

Comment: Yes Android NDK has prebuilt for arm-eabi. Sorry, can't tell about iMX6 table, don't have much idea about that platform.

Comment: You will a kernel source tree corresponding to the kernel on your device.   The toolchain in the NDK ought to be able to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make this new camera work as a standard camera through Android's camera API?

In that case, unless your tablet has a particularly unusual configuration, simply installing a new kernel driver will do nothing.  You still need an Android camera HAL module implementation that converts commands and data between your driver's kernel interface and Android's camera framework code.

Comment: Can you explain ? Because I don't understand ... What's the difference between HAL and driver ?